# Show progress bar while running UI actions in the background in WPF

Tags: wpf, progress-bar

I'm having problem in displaying progress bar while running another UI actions in background.

I have an UI action where I'm drawing some images on canvas which is time consuming process till then I want to display a progress bar so that screen doesn't look hanged.

With my code Progress bar is getting visible after UI action is completed.

Below is the code snippet

```
public void OnShowAllTrackClick()
{
        //Makes the Progress bar visible

        SpinnerVisibility = Visibility.Visible; 

        //Dispatcher to draw some images on screen
        Action action = new Action(ShowAllTracksThread);
        
       System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action);

       SpinnerVisibility = Visibility.Visible; //Hides the Progress bar

}
```

Comment: Take a look at async in C#, I ussually go that way for this sort of things.  What you basically need to do is to run your primary method (drawing images) in UI thread, and your OnShowAllTrackClick method on different thread.

Comment: If your task for _drawing some images on canvas_ must be run on UI thread and completely blocks the thread, you cannot update ProgressBar value during that task anyway.